# How to transfer file to internal usb storage on Samsung Note?

Tags: file-transfer, samsung-galaxy-note

I am trying to install a p12 certificate on my Samsung Note.  From what I've read, this can be accomplished with: menu->settings->Location and Security->Install from USB Storage (or SDCard storage, depending on the phone).

So, how do I transfer a file to the USB storage?

Comment: transfer a file to usb storage you mean from pc to phone usb storage or from phone to flash drive ?

Answer (score 1):

**For transfering files thorugh pc to USB:**
Goto settings>about phone> and tap **build bumber** several times until it shows you are **now developer**.
Now goto settings> developer options> enable **debugging mode**.
Now try connecting to pc  (Make sure you have **USB drivers** installed).

**For transfering files from phone to USB:***
Make sure you have working **otg cable**.
Use **es explorer**(recommended) to copy paste the files from phone to USB.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings-applications-USB debugging and enable that.
If you're running ICS, go to settings-developer options instead.
Now when you connect your phone via USB, it will show up as a mass storage device and you can directly copy files to/from the mass storage (and SD card if you have one).

Try placing the certificate in the root directory of your SD card and then import it.

Comment: In fact, you should put files not onto SD card, but in internal memory.